# Change form values with Javascript and submit to an AJAX'ed View?

Tags: views, 8, javascript

In Drupal 8, you can trigger a refresh for a View by invoking:

```
$('.view-name').trigger('RefreshView');
```

The view I am trying this on has an exposed form on the page. I notice it does not respect the form values when triggering this event - is there another one I can use or does this sort of assignment:

```
    // date button
    $('button.c-sortby__date').bind('click', function() {
      var old_sort = $('input[name="sort_by"]').attr('value');

      $('input[name="sort_by"]').attr('value', 'changed');

      var order = $('input[name="sort_order"]').attr('value');

      // if the sort was relevance before, force DESC
      if (old_sort == 'search_api_relevance') {
        order = 'DESC';
      } else {
        if (order == 'ASC') {
          order = 'DESC';
        } else if (order == 'DESC') {
          order = 'ASC';
        }
      }

      $('input[name="sort_order"]').attr('value', order);
      $('form#views-exposed-form-acquia-search-results').submit();
    });
```

not work?

Note: if the view config is *not* AJAX set, the above Javascript works when triggering the submit() event of the form.

Comment: I can't answer your specific function, but I have done something quite similar in the past triggering $.click() on whichever button would do it manually.

Comment: `I notice it does not respect the form values when triggering this event` can you elaborate more on this?